# Can't get component schema title in Tridion GUI extension

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

I'm trying to get the shema title for the component using next javascript code:

`var component = $models.getItem(id);
component.getSchema().getTitle()
component.getSchema().getInfo().Title;`

the result of getSchema().getTitle() and getSchema().getInfo().Title is 'undefined'. What's wrong with my code? How can I get the component schema title?

Comment: These properties all load asynchronously, you need to add listeners to the "load" event. I'm sure there's examples on this site on how to do that.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use code like following

```
 var schema = $models.getItem(id).getSchema();
    var title;
    function loaded()
    {
        title = schema .getTitle();
    }
    $evt.addEventHandler(schema , "load", loaded);
    schema.load(true);
```